# What is adding a date suffix (access.log.20210909.gz) not the default for logrotate, instead of changing filenames every time (.1, .2.gz, .3.gz)?

Tags: logs, logrotate

Why is the simple solution "adding a datetime suffix to log filenames, e.g. access.log.20210909.gz" **not** `logrotate`'s default behaviour? Rather than doing a renaming of *all log files' filenames* every time we rotate (which is obviously more complex)?

**Said differently, why does `logrotate` uses a solution that implies to rename *every file* at each period, when there is a solution which only requires to rename a given file *only once* in its life?**

There surely is a reason behind this, but I don't currently see it.

---

Example: Let's take the standard `logrotate` rule for Apache that gives:

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
/var/log/apache2/access.log.1
/var/log/apache2/access.log.2.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.3.gz
...
/var/log/apache2/access.log.100.gz
```

When we want to backup logs to a distant computer, then *as the filenames change every time it is rotated*, the files risk to be re-transferred again and again (depending on the backup software).

Also, these (changing) filenames are not very handy for human people to look at, because they don't tell anything about the date.

**Would there be any drawback (that I haven't seen yet) to ask `logorate` to use this scheme instead:**

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log     
/var/log/apache2/access.log.20210908_0100.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.20210907_0100.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.20210906_0100.gz
...
```

**?**

Comment: Note: I edited to put the question on-topic and not opinion-based anymore. The question is now: why does logrotate uses a solution that implies to rename every file at each period, when there is a solution which only requires to rename a given file *only once* and never anymore?

Answer (score 1):

There is not downsides to this, except if you want to logrotate multiple times in a day, you should add the time to the pattern.

Also imagine you rotate everyday, but also if the file is too big. You will get an error on those rotates.

Comment: Thank you. To be even more precise: why the simple solution "adding a datetime suffix" is not the default behaviour of `logrotate`, rather than doing a rotation of *all log files' filenames* every time we rotate (which is obviously more complex!). What this complex solution is the default, when there is a simple solution? There surely is a reason behind this, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define in a consistent manner what date should be used. Not every date will be appropriate in every situation. Here are a few to start:

- Date of creation
- Date first written
- Date cycled
- Date of last log entry (i.e. last modified)

Any of these dates presupposes at most one logfile per day. If that's acceptable then there is no particular reason why you shouldn't use a date suffix for your log files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Historically, what made Linux sysadmins use this complex method (which needs an additional tool: `logrotate`) instead of the KISS (simple and stupid) naming convention `access.log.20230421_1059.gz`, which wouldn't require any `logrotate` software, which wouldn't require to rename files for every rotation, etc. What is the historical reason behind this decision?